# Any way to link vimeo video to native player on Android?

Tags: android, video, video-streaming, vimeo, vimeo-android

I am building a portfolio site.

I am using the `http://player.vimeo.com/video/9999...` format for my links.

On an iOS device, these links open up in phone's native player and play nicely.

But on Android, they open a generally pseudo-page, that plays badly. Only when you then click the fullscreen button does it go into the native playing mode.

This is really annoying.

Is there any scripting magic to create a link that will open directly to the fullscreen native player on Android?

Comment: How did you make it work on iOS?

Answer (score 1):

According to what I could find the only way to access the info for that would be with a Pro subscription. This answer might be old, but it's all I could find:

> Tommy Penner STAFF  2 years ago Sorry, it's not possible to link
>   directly to the .mp4 file coming from our servers. The only way to
>   access the 'raw' transcoded files is with a PRO subscription. Link:
>   [vimeo.com/faq/pro](http://vimeo.com/faq/pro)